# efficient category templating

Tags: templates, categories

In the URL **www.site/recipes/meat**, the segment 2 is a category, so, to make this work, I use a template with the category´s name:

the category template, is named (**meat**):

```
{embed="recipes/.recipes" url_title="meat"}
```

The main template, is named (**.recipes**):

```
{embed="estrutura/.template"}
     {exp:stash:set name='main'}
       .........
     {/exp:stash:set}
```

So, when the category appears in the url, the main template **.recipes** is called by the category template. With,
**www.site/recipes/meat**, all the entries of this category are listed.

It's working fine, but I have to create a small category template for each category. I'm curious to know if a more efficient templating way exists?

Stéphane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default EE looks for the category indicator in the URL, eg www.site/recipes/category/meat, then output content based on that category url title (/meat).

If you don't want to use the category indicator you'll need to use the LowSeg2Cat addon  http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat - you can then use one entries tag and one template for any category, simply by using Seg2Cat to pull in the category ID:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" category="{segment_2_category_id}"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Bluedreamer, thanks for your tip! I didn't think about LowSeg2Cat.